DBeaver disable ctrl+click = definition
My goal is disable ctrl+click leads to table definition.
I've searched and I've gone through most of the preferences. I even exported them to a csv file to try and search them for the thing to disable.
When I'm trying to do a bunch of copy/paste I like to hold down ctrl button and I'd like to be able to that within DBeaver and not have to copy it to notepad++ before doing these types of operations.

The easiest way is to ask developers themselves: https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues
Their support is quite friendly and fast.
